# Flask refactoring

Tags: python, flask, refactoring

I am trying to make a web project in Flask. In short, it is a HTML/CSS site where you can input some data and either the area or circumference of the rectangle is shown.

My problem is that I pretty much repeated the same code both for the circumference and the area parts. I have managed to do the input validation and calculations in another .py file (web_rectangle.py), but now I am stuck.

Here is one of the two input HTML files (they are pretty much identical):

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/grids.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.css">
    <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/expletus-sans:n4,n7,n5,i7,i4,n6,i6,i5:all;nova-square:n4:all;trykker:n4:all.js"></script>
    <title>Omkredsen af et rektangel</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="hdfo_td_side" background="static/header_left.png">
                </td>
                <td class="td_center" background="static/header_center.png">
                    <h1>Rektangel - areal</h1>
                </td>
                <td class="hdfo_td_side" background="static/header_right.png">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </header>

    <div class="line"></div>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav_bg"></div>
        <div class="nav_text">
            <a href="/">Forside</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="line"></div>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="main_left col grid_3">
                <p>Formel for arealet af et rektangel:</p>
                <p class="formula">A = l * b</p>
                <p>(A) står for areal, (l) for rektanglets længde og (b) for rektanglets bredde.</p>
                <p>Husk at i geometri skal det man finder (her arealet) skrives med stort bogstav, mens de variabler man bruger (for eksempel 'længde'), skal skrives med små bogstaver.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main_right col grid_5">
                <h3>Indtast data</h3>

                <form action="/rect_area" method="GET">
                    Længde
                    <br>
                    <input {% if error_l %} class="error_l" {% endif %} type="text" name="length" value="{{ length }}">
                    <br>
                    <br>Bredde
                    <br>
                    <input {% if error_w %} class="error_w" {% endif %} type="text" name="width" value="{{ width }}">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Se svar">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </form>
                <div>
                    {% if input_text %}
                    <p>{{ input_text }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if input_error %}
                    <p>{{ input_error }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {% if result %}
                    <p>Omkredsen er: {{ result }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="hdfo_td_side" background="static/footer_left.png">
                </td>
                <td class="td_center" background="static/footer_center.png">
                    <p class="footer_text">(C) Copyright 2015, Daniel Holm Hansen</p>
                </td>
                <td class="hdfo_td_side" background="static/footer_right.png">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </footer>

    <img class="footer_logo" src="../static/logo_dhh_white_xs.png" width="120" alt="Made by DHH">
</body>
```

index.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from web_rectangle import rect_area, rect_circ, test_val

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/rect_circ')
def circ_input():
    #Inputs from web
    length = request.args.get('length')
    width = request.args.get('width')

    #Predefined values
    error_l = ''
    error_w = ''
    input_text = '''Indtast værdierne for længde og bredde. Du må kun bruge tal.
                 Brug punktum i stedet for komma før decimaltal.'''
    input_error = '''Brug kun tal større end nul og punktum i stedet for komma 
                  før decimaltal.'''

    #Test length and width for valid inputs
    if length and width:
        return_val_l = test_val(length)
        length = return_val_l[0]
        error_l = return_val_l[1]

        return_val_w = test_val(width)
        width = return_val_w[0]
        error_w = return_val_w[1]
    #Test length for valid inputs when width == ''
    elif length:
        return_val_l = test_val(length)
        length = return_val_l[0]
        error_l = return_val_l[1]
        error_w = 'Indtast tal'
    #Test width for valid inputs when length == ''
    elif width:
        return_val_w = test_val(width)
        width = return_val_w[0]
        error_w = return_val_w[1]
        error_l = 'Indtast tal'
    #Both length and width == ''
    else:
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_area.html',
            input_text = input_text
        )

    #Final outputs depending on error types from input tests - if any 
    if  error_l == '' and error_w == '':        
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_circ.html',
            result = rect_circ(length, width),
            length = length,
            width = width
        )
    elif error_l == '' and error_w != '':
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_circ.html',
            length = length,
            width = error_w,
            error_w = error_w,
            input_error = input_error
        )
    elif error_l != '' and error_w == '':
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_circ.html',
            length = error_l,
            width = width,
            error_l = error_l,
            input_error = input_error
        )
    elif error_l != '' and error_w != '':
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_circ.html',
            length = error_l,
            width = error_w,
            error_l = error_l,
            error_w = error_w,
            input_error = input_error
        )
    else:
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_circ.html',
            input_text = input_text
        )


@app.route('/rect_area')
def area_input():
    #Inputs from web
    length = request.args.get('length')
    width = request.args.get('width')

    #Predefined values
    error_l = ''
    error_w = ''
    input_text = '''Indtast værdierne for længde og bredde. Du må kun bruge tal.
                 Brug punktum i stedet for komma før decimaltal.'''
    input_error = '''Brug kun tal større end nul og punktum i stedet for komma 
                  før decimaltal.'''

    #Test length and width for valid inputs
    if length and width:
        return_val_l = test_val(length)
        length = return_val_l[0]
        error_l = return_val_l[1]

        return_val_w = test_val(width)
        width = return_val_w[0]
        error_w = return_val_w[1]
    #Test length for valid inputs when width == ''
    elif length:
        return_val_l = test_val(length)
        length = return_val_l[0]
        error_l = return_val_l[1]
        error_w = 'Indtast tal'
    #Test width for valid inputs when length == ''
    elif width:
        return_val_w = test_val(width)
        width = return_val_w[0]
        error_w = return_val_w[1]
        error_l = 'Indtast tal'
    #Both length and width == ''
    else:
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_area.html',
            input_text = input_text
        )

    #Final outputs depending on error types from input tests - if any 
    if  error_l == '' and error_w == '':        
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_area.html',
            result = rect_area(length, width),
            length = length,
            width = width
        )
    elif error_l == '' and error_w != '':
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_area.html',
            length = length,
            width = error_w,
            error_w = error_w,
            input_error = input_error
        )
    elif error_l != '' and error_w == '':
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_area.html',
            length = error_l,
            width = width,
            error_l = error_l,
            input_error = input_error
        )
    elif error_l != '' and error_w != '':
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_area.html',
            length = error_l,
            width = error_w,
            error_l = error_l,
            error_w = error_w,
            input_error = input_error
        )
    else:
        return render_template(
            'rectangle_area.html',
            input_text = input_text
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

web_rectangle.py:

```
#This script is for WEB use only.
#It is used by another script calling its funtions.


def rect_area(length, width):
    return length * width

def rect_circ(length, width):
    return 2 * length + 2 * width

def test_val(val):
    try:
        val = float(val)
        if val <= 0:
            error = 'Indtast et tal større end 0'
        else:
            error = ''
    except ValueError:
        error = 'Fejl i indtastning'
    return val, error
```

I hope someone can give me a hint or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong then you are looking for making the code more modular by eliminating duplication of code. Here you can get most out of BLUEPRINTS -http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/ .

You can code a common shape_input.py and define a single method (def) for it. Circle or rectangle can be passed to the def as an argument. This way you will end up by eliminating the duplicate code. While to make a call to different HTML templates - views - could be at your rescue.

Hope this helps.